# How can i create multiple RelativeLayouts(with existing xml layout) in an LinearLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to put multiple RelativeLayouts in one LinearLayout programmatically. Instead of using a ListView. My layout XML looks like following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background_select_app" >

   <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scroller"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#80000000" >

      <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="#FFFFFF" >
      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

and following is the RelativeLayout which I want to add as child in LinearLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="280dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:background="@drawable/row"
   android:gravity="center" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:textColor="#333333" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can i do it programmatically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is my solution worked out!

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
public void testgenerate() {

        LinearLayout rootLaout=findViewById(R.id.idofliner);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            RelativeLayout inflate = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.relativelayutid, null);
            rootLaout.addView(inflate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no need to nest a RelativeLayout in your LinearLayout, you can achieve the same as Linearlayout with just a single RelativeLayout (so your view hierarchy has one Layout less to traverse --> improves performance ) or if you simply want to align your elements verticaly / horizontally than use only one LinearLayout instead of an extra RelativeLayout

Im not sure what you want to do, but to me it sounds like that  RecyclerView or ListView is what you are looking for?